# Is it possible to bypass OpenEdge auditing?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, auditing

The subject says it all really.

Does anyone know if there is a way to execute Progress ABL code that modifies a database (with OE auditing active) AND bypass OpenEdge's auditing functionality?

So say there is a database with auditing enabled and a user table called client with OpenEdge auditing set up to monitor for CRUD operations against the client table..

Is it possible to programmatically update the client table whilst making sure that no audit record is created?

Thanks

Comment: What is the use case? Or do you only seek confirmation that the audit functionality is bullet proof?

Comment: Yeah, its more around how bullet proof the auditing is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for something like "DISABLE TRIGGERS" then no, there is no built-in OpenEdge feature that allows an ordinary user to (temporarily) disable auditing.

An "audit administrator" can, of course, disable auditing:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P135000

but I don't think that is what you are looking for.

It is just software and bits and security is a never ending arms race so in theory a sufficiently dedicated attacker with deep pockets and a lot of time on their hands could probably do something evil.  But that is no more or less true for OE Auditing than it would be for any other similar product.

Unless your real name is Bruce Schneier you are almost certainly better off with OE Auditing than you would be with a "home grown" solution.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I guess I want to know if there are any NO-AUDIT modifiers or similar that would prevent audit records from being created off the back of CRUD operations.  I've set up auditing and know about enabling/ disabling and configuration etc.  I just want to be aware of any workarounds a developer may attempt in order to circum-navigate db auditing..

Comment: That's what the first line above addresses ;)  SFAIK there is no such thing.  The closest you could get would be something like:  http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P143113 but that requires "audit admin" privileges.  It seems obvious but I guess the lesson would be to make sure that you control audit admin very, very carefully.